# HTML Javascript Onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

CAN ANYONE PLEASE HELP ME FIND OUT WHY THE ONCLICK ISNT WORKING... I also have a CSS sheet connecting my span classes but for some reason onclick isnt working...

```
<head>
    <link href="stylizing.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>     
        function showCode()
        {
            document.getElementById("latestDiscountCode").className ="unhideBlock textAlignLeft";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<p class="textAlignLeft" onclick = "showCode();">
    <span class="xxx">  
        CLICK ME
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? Are you sure there's an element with that ID?

Comment: I don't see the element with `id="latestDiscountCode"` in your HTML. Can you please include it too?

Comment: Checking the JavaScript console should *always* be the first step in debugging.  If you are unfamiliar with the console, check out this link on how to access it:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you use **document.getElementById**, you need specify the "id":

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Example by:** http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a typo in either your id name or your stylesheet class names. The code you supplied does not include an element with an of "latestDiscountCode" so I have created one as an example. If you click on the CLICK ME text you will see your browers DOM inspector that the correct classes are added to the div.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="stylizing.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>     
            function showCode()
            {
                 document.getElementById("latestDiscountCode").className ="unhideBlock textAlignLeft";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p class="textAlignLeft" onclick = "showCode();">
           <span class="xxx">  
           CLICK ME
           </span>
       </p>

       <p id="latestDiscountCode">
       foo
       </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no **id** specified on your element .

```
<p class="textAlignLeft" id="latestDiscountCode" onclick = "showCode();">
....
</p>
```

**The id can be placed on whatever element you want to change the classname of. Code above is assuming this is the "p" tag.**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need that semi-colon ;

```
<p class="textAlignLeft" onclick = "showCode()">
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF. Please do not try to answer questions if you are not sure. Are you sure the problem is due to the `;`?

Answer (score -1):

<del>Move the `<script>` to the *end* of the body. Otherwise, it'll execute before the DOM's been loaded. Credits to @Federico.</del>

<del>Alternatively, listen for DOMContentLoaded.</del>

Comment: Since the script is being called by the `onclick` in the HTML, this is not the issue.